# Array name can't be l-value means this?

Tags: c

For example,

I declared variable like this,

```
char szBuffer[12] = {"Hello"};
char szData[12] = {"Cheese"};

szBuffer = szData;
```

is error, since `szBuffer` can't be l-value.

`szBuffer` has its own address, for example, `0x0012345678`, and `szBuffer`'s value is also its address, `0x0012345678`.

So I think "array name can't be l-value" means that an array's address and its value have to be equal.

Am I right?

If I'm right, why do they have to be equal?

Comment: Succinctly, you can't assign one array to another; that's why 'string assignments' don't work well either — you have to use `strcpy()` (or `memmove()` or `memcpy()`).  For general arrays, `memmove()` or `memcpy()` is appropriate rather than `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> array name can't be l-value

It means an array can not be used as l-value or left hand side of the assignment operator (not to be confused with initialization). An l-value must be modifiable. You can modify the contents of array but not the array itself.

In `C` you can not assign to arrays. Though you can intialize them.

You should use [`strcpy(szBuffer, szData)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) or [`memcpy(szBuffer, szData, 12)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy).

Also there is no need of `{}` in the initialization from string literal.

If you insist on using `operator =`, you need to put your string in a struct because struct object copy is allowed in `C`.

ex:

```
struct string {
  char name[12];
};

struct string szBuffer = {"Hello"};
struct string szData = {"Cheese"};

szBuffer = szData;
```

Comment: The example attempts to assign to array and is wrong.

Comment: only C? or other language also can't assign to array name?

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks. Edited.

Comment: @mathcom There are programming languages/scripts were it is possible to assign to arrays. I am talking only for C here.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't mean such a thing.

Array's address isn't value of array in general.

Arrays in expression except for operands of `sizeof` and unary `&` operator are automatically converted to pointers to first arguments of that array.

Therefore, the converted pointer is not an l-value and you cannot assign there.

Answer (score 0):

*array name can't be l-value* means that array names cannot be used on the left side of an `=`.

To be more clearer, you need a **modifiable l-value** on the left side of a `=`

---

Arrays are **modifiable l-value** when they are used with indices like `arr[i]`.

But array name themselves are not, and hence cannot be used on the left side of a `=`

Answer (score 0):

An L-value is something that can appear on the left hand side of an assignment.  Examples:  Scalar variables, array elements, pointer dereferences.  An array name is not an L-value in C.  Instead, you can do one of two things:  (1) a pointer assignment, if you just need a pointer to the array, or (2) an array copy, if you really need to copy the array itself.